# How Can I Short this lines..?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
lines = []
while True:
    value1 = raw_input("\t ")
    if value1:
        lines.append(value1.upper())
    else:
        break
```

Do short as you can using lambda() or any thing I have to make code as short as possible so..

Comment: This is not [CodeGolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Perhaps you should try it there.

Comment: how did `line` become `lines`?

Comment: Why to shorten it?..

Comment: @dmg: Don't try it on the code golf site... I'm pretty sure this is an invalid question there as well.

Comment: @Bair Well, rephrased as "use python to read lines from stdin with a prompt having a tab and append to a list" or something like that. It probably even has an answer.

Comment: Why is this tagged python2 __and__ python3? `raw_input` doesn't even exist in python3.

Comment: @Rawing Why _is_ this at all?

Comment: Warm and Heavy welcome for Parth Mehta on SO.

Comment: @TanveerAlam And to all who have not read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check out usage of the builtin [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) with a sentinel, then apply some lambda to combine `raw_iter` with `upper`. That will be a single line. Then revert everything to the original version and deny that you've ever done that.

Comment: @ParthMehta Shorter code does not mean _better code_.

Comment: @bereal thanks for the sharing because some OTHER peoples are using SO for the pointing purpose only.

Comment: My full code is def main():
    print "\n\t Enter Multiline values \n\t ___________________________\n"
    lines = []
    while True:
        value1 = raw_input("\t ")
        if value1:
            lines.append(value1.upper())
        else:
            break

    print "\t In UpperCase \n\t ___________________________\n"
    for sentence in lines:
        print "\t %s" % (sentence)
    print "\n"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(

Answer (score 0):

Two lines shorter, and I would argue better readability:

```
lines = []
value1 = raw_input("\t ")
while value1:
    lines.append(value1.upper())
    value1 = raw_input("\t ")
```

Instead of using an `if-else` clause to exit the loop, we check the condition in the loop, although, this will make the scope of `value1` beyond the scope of the `while` loop. Although this is fine in many situations, it is worse in some.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iter with a sentinel value which is an empty string in this case

```
lines = []
for value in iter(raw_input, ""):
    if value:
        lines.append(value.upper())
```

which can become a list comprehension:

```
lines = [value.upper() for value in iter(raw_input, "") if value]
```

Comment: @ParthMehta. yep I was pretty sure it would ;)